# Using `ToneAnalyzerV3` from the ibm_watson python package, how can I exclude a specific tone from being included?

Tags: tone-analyzer

This returns all tones from the analyzer

```py
# returns all tones (anger, fear, sadness, tentative, analytical
tone_analysis = tone_analyzer.tone({'text': text}, content_type='application/json').get_result()
```

How can I exclude the 'analytical' tone from being returned from the analysis?

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this, but it looks like the API no longer accepts the tones=[] list of tones to limit its analysis to.  https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer  I also don't see a documented way to get confidence scores for all tones, instead of just the dominant ones.

Comment: From the python-sdk docs here: http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/python-sdk/v1.0.2/apis/watson_developer_cloud.tone_analyzer_v3.html
Looks like as of late 2017, the scores have to pass a threshold (0.5) to be returned:  Attr str tone_id:
  The unique, non-localized identifier of the tone. 2017-09-21: The service can return results for the following tone IDs: anger, fear, joy, and sadness (emotional tones); analytical, confident, and tentative (language tones). The service returns results only for tones whose scores meet a minimum threshold of 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it looks like the answer (as of 2017-09-21) is, "You can't."

The documentation for the python-sdk indicates as much.  http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/python-sdk/v1.0.2/apis/watson_developer_cloud.tone_analyzer_v3.html

See specifically:

Under ToneAnalyzerV3.tone(), parameter tones - you can no longer specify the tone list to return:

> tones (list[str]) – `2017-09-21`: Deprecated. The service continues to
> accept the parameter for backward-compatibility, but the parameter no
> longer affects the response.

Under ToneAnalyzerV3.DocumentAnalysis(), the attribute tones - the service only returns tones with scores of value >= 0.5, which means you can't do your own softmax to exclude analytical:

> Attr list[ToneScore] tones:
> (optional) `2017-09-21`: An array of ToneScore objects that provides the results of the analysis for each qualifying tone of the
> document. The array includes results for any tone whose score is at
> least 0.5. The array is empty if no tone has a score that meets this
> threshold.

Under ToneAnalyzerV3.SentenceAnalysis(), the attribute tones - same story:

> Attr list[ToneScore] tones:   (optional) `2017-09-21`: An array of
> ToneScore objects that provides the results of the analysis for each
> qualifying tone of the sentence. The array includes results for any
> tone whose score is at least 0.5. The array is empty if no tone has a
> score that meets this threshold.

Comment: Pity. It would be a useful feature.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about why they removed it.  I can think of two reasons:  1) people were "incorrectly" using values less than 0.5, or 2) people were using the Watson system to train their own systems!  Hmmm I wonder if you could still do that with clipping the probability... I don't think it would work that well.